# How to put rounded dome on non-circular surface (Modeling rounded shoes)?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm modeling the shoes/boots of a character's ability from Hunter X Hunter. They're like clown shoes, in particular they have a bulbous front section that's like if they were molded around a ball. The core problem is I'm trying to build a symmetrical, rounded dome on a non-circular base that connects to the edges of the base.

[image: Crazy Slots' Boots]

I have the base sole of the shoe built in Blender, but I can't find a satisfactory way to make the shape of the top of the boot in the front. My biggest problem is after finding a way to make the dome, I have to attach it all around the edge of the sole without destroying a smooth/round shape.

I've tried several different approaches:

- Using proportional editing to pull up the roof of the sole
- Shrink wrapping over balls or ellipsoid
- Using the warp modifier on a plane
- Trying to create a Nurbs curve and use the curve modifier to fit the shape
- Manually snapping the points of a ball or ellipsoid to the edge of the sole
- Sculpting the top of the shoe from a metaball

The sole base seen from an angle:
[image: Sole from angle]

Sole base seen from the top (wider end is the front):
[image: Sole from top]

Does anyone have suggestions/examples for how I could essentially make a dome from something non-circular? Maybe an extrusion of some sort that tapers/smooths off at the top? I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to build this model for 3D printing for a cosplay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe begin with this kind of topology?

[image]

Comment: Could you give some more information on how you made that topology? 
Also, how would you go about smoothing it out starting from this? Are there any particular tools or methods you think would be best? Thank you for the help!

Comment: cut the half of a cube, mirror it, extrude, move some edges, etc, as for the the smoothing, when you're glad with the general shape, add a Subidivision Surface, don't apply it if you don't need to (and if you do, make sure that you always keep a non-applied copy), put some support edges along the edges that are supposed to stay sharp

Comment: Marking this as the solution! I was able to use subdivision surface + a smooth modifier, tweak the edges a bit manually, and then use the loop tools curve to round out the sole. Thank you!